# Unable to connect bot to Skype For Business Online

Tags: azure, office365, botframework

I am unable to connect my bot to Skype For Business (SFB) Online. I have followed below URL for the same -

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/Skype-For-Business-Bot-Framework/docs/overview

I am the global administrator of my Office 365 account and have the privileges to connect the bot to SFB Online. It has been more than 8 hours the bot has been registered.

The first command (Import-PSSession) works fine. 
The second command (New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint) gives below error - 
**Cmdlet invocation error
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint], CmdletInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Error processing cmdlet request,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.PlatformService.NewPlatformServiceAppEndpointConfigCmdlet
    + PSComputerName        : adminin1.online.lync.com**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the part of your code where the exception has thrown...

Comment: Hi Bob, thank you for your reply. The problem is not with the bot code; but it is while registering the bot to Skype For Business Online tenant. The powershell command that is giving the above pasted error is : New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint 41ec7d50-ba91-1208-73ee-136b88859725 -Name NameOfTheBot -Uri sip:username@yourdomain.com

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Was your **-Uri** end with **.com**? I've got similar error when I tried **-Uri sip:username@domainnotendwithdotcom** but when I changed it to use the alias name that end with **onmicrosoft.com** then the command work fine.

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for your reply.

My Uri ends with onmicrosoft.com; but still I am encountering the error. Is there anything else I need to do which is not mentioned in the document.

Comment: Hi zee, I've just found out the reason is not the domain name must end with .com. The reason is the Uri I used is a existing user/tenant so the command error, when I changed it to a new user, the command succeed and it will auto create the user for the bot.

Comment: Hi Nick, it perfectly works fine with a new user. Thank you very much for your help. But still, the bot is having some problem while communicating with SFB Online. I am receiving error on the Bot as "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Unauthorized" and on the SFB Chat Window, the error is "Error happened in contacting target user". I have also observed that the Bot is showing "Presence Unknown" instead of status Online/ Available. Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: zee - for that error, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44048053/bot-framework-skype-for-business-channel/44132514#44132514