# How to connect a bot to Skype for business

Tags: powershell, botframework, skype-for-business

I am currently working with the Microsoft Bot Framework and am trying to connect my bot to the new Skype for business channel.

I've followed the instructions:

1. Download and install the Skype for Business Online Connector module
2. Open Windows PowerShell as Administrator and run the following:

   Import-PSSession (New-CsOnlineSession -Credential (Get-Credential))
3. Enter your Admin credentials
4. Run the following cmdlet:

   New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint -ApplicationId botid -Name NameOfTheBot -Uri sip:username@yourdomain

I got our tenant admin to enter his credentials and also to create a domain account for the bot with an Office 365 licence. (I tried first to register bot without an Office 365 licence assigned).

When the bot account had an office 365 licence and tried to call the New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint I got the following error:

```
Cmdlet invocation error
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint], CmdletInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Error processing cmdlet request,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.PlatformService.NewPlatformServiceAppEndpointConfigCmdlet
    + PSComputerName        : admin1e.online.lync.com

Could not find the application endpoint
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Rtc.M...cation endpoint:PlatformServiceCmdletException) [New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint], PlatformServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Could not get application endpoint or the Uri is already present as an User in BVD,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.PlatformService.NewPlatformServiceAppEndpointConfigCmdlet
    + PSComputerName        : admin1e.online.lync.com
```

Without the Office 365 licence I got the following error:

```
Cmdlet invocation error
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint], CmdletInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Error processing cmdlet request,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.PlatformService.NewPlatformServiceAppEndpointConfigCmdlet
    + PSComputerName        : admin1e.online.lync.com

Exception of type 'Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.PlatformService.ProvisioningLibrary.ApplicationEndpointProvisioningException' was thrown.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Rtc.M...on' was thrown.:PlatformServiceCmdletException) [New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint], ApplicationEndpointProvisioningException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Exception of type 'Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.PlatformService.ProvisioningLibrary.ApplicationEndpointProvisioningException' was thrown.,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.PlatformService.NewPlatformServiceAppEndpointConfigCmdlet
    + PSComputerName        : admin1e.online.lync.com
```

I've also followed some of the more generic info around the Skype for Business connector as detailed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/trusted-application-api/docs/trustedapplicationendpoint

I've also tried to use a new account as mentioned in this issue but got the same error: [Unable to connect bot to Skype For Business Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43977783/unable-to-connect-bot-to-skype-for-business-online)

Comment: Same issue here. Have the feeling that a step is missing. You're now trying to add a Microsoft App ID to an Azure AD tenant without ever having registered it or something like that. I've been looking into it but haven't found a solution so far.

Comment: Tried this, did not work for me. https://github.com/Microsoft/Partner-Center-Bot/blob/master/docs/Preconsent.md

Answer (score 4):

You need to target the domain:

sip:botname@company.onmicrosoft.com

It appears it will not work if you target your custom domains.

Comment: Seems to work, at least doesn't throw an error. Will check tomorrow if the bot really appears as the documentation states this can take some hours to provision.

Comment: I can see my bot has provisioned properly now and can search by it's name. It does however show with a status of presence unknown.

Comment: Same here, and when chatting to it, the response is 'Error happened in contacting target user'

Comment: Same here, it shows as unknown and when I chat it says: 'We couldn't send this message: ...', (like when users are disconnected). Do I just need to wait for the bot to be enabled? Or something is wrong?